# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'select_by_visible_text' while using select_by_visible_text() method on elements through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

After writing data to form I get the pop-up menu.

I try to select some from it and continue with selenium, but all variants are in `div` tag

```
<div class="menu menu_theme_islands menu_size_m sg-datalist menu__control i-bem sg-datalist_js_inited menu_js_inited menu__control_js_inited sg-datalist_focused menu_focused menu_hovered" data-bem="{&quot;menu&quot;:{},&quot;sg-datalist&quot;:{}}" role="menu" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="uniq155307974964633">
    <div class="menu__item menu__item_theme_islands i-bem i-bem" data-bem="{&quot;menu__item&quot;:{&quot;val&quot;:30863}}" role="menuitem" id="uniq155307974964651" aria-disabled="">Магазин детской одежды</div>
    <div class="menu__item menu__item_theme_islands i-bem i-bem" data-bem="{&quot;menu__item&quot;:{&quot;val&quot;:30859}}" role="menuitem" id="uniq155307974964652" aria-disabled="">Детский магазин</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying

```
company_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Начните печатать и выберите из списка']")
company_id.send_keys("Магазин детской одежды")
time.sleep(1)
driver.select.select_by_visible_text("Магазин детской одежды")
```

But it's return an

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'select_by_visible_text'
```

How can I select smth from the pop-up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
Select select=Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.menu__control_js_inited"))
select.select_by_index(1)
```

**Option 2  :**If above doesn't work try this way.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.menu__control_js_inited").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='menu__item menu__item_theme_islands i-bem i-bem'])[1]"))).click()
```

Options 3:

```
element=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.menu__control_js_inited")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='menu__item menu__item_theme_islands i-bem i-bem'])[1]"))).click()
```

Please make sure you need to have following imports.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

Comment: But how can I select it in the menu?

Comment: @PetrPetrov : Are you sure it is dropdwon menu?can i have the url?

Comment: @PetrPetrov : updated the answer see if it helps.Index(1) is the first element in dropdown

Comment: I have an error `UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>`

Comment: did you try option 2 which i mentioned.If above doesn't work try this

Comment: @PetrPetrov : please try option 2 or 3 it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'select_by_visible_text'
```

...implies that you have tried to use `select_by_visible_text()` through a *WebDriver* instance which is not supported.

### Solution

To click on the item with text as **Магазин детской одежды** as the desired elements are `<div>` elements you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='menu menu_theme_islands menu_size_m sg-datalist menu__control i-bem sg-datalist_js_inited menu_js_inited menu__control_js_inited sg-datalist_focused menu_focused menu_hovered' and starts-with(@aria-activedescendant, 'uniq')]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='menu__item menu__item_theme_islands i-bem i-bem' and text()='Магазин детской одежды']"))).click()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you did not get:

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'select'
```

As this is not a native attribute of the selenium driver.

You need to import the Select Class

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

Then code should look like:

```
company_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Начните печатать и выберите из списка']")
company_id.send_keys("Магазин детской одежды")
select = Select(yourMenuElement)
el = select.select_by_visible_text("Магазин детской одежды")

print(el.text)
```

Edit:
From your html, there is no select tag and the above might not work.

You could try this:

```
company_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Начните печатать и выберите из списка']")
input_text = "Магазин детской одежды"
company_id.send_keys(input_text)
menu = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[role="menuitem"]')
select_el = None
for el in menu:
    if el.text == input_text:
        select_el = el
        break
if select_el is not None:
    "Do stuff"
else:
    print("Unable to find element with tex: {}".format(input_text))
```

Comment: It doesn't work: `UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>`